# Trying to mock a named commonjs module in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, commonjs

I've searched for days on how to accomplish this and nothing i've tried has worked. I have an `authenticate` module that I share among other modules, and I'm wanting to create a mock for it using jest, in my my unit tests. Here's what i have currently:

*authenticate.js*

```
const got = require('got');

const authenticate = async (options) => {
  let res = ...api request using got library to retrieve token...

  return { data: res.access_token };
};

exports.authenticate = authenticate;
```

*schedule.js*

```
const schedule = async (options) {
  // import authenticate library
  const authenticate = require('./authenticate');

  const login = await authenticate.authenticate(options);

  const result;

  ...stuff to set result...
  result = {
    data: 'success'
  };

  return result;
};

exports.schedule = schedule;
```

*shedule.test.js*

```
const scheduler = require('./schedule');

test('[schedule]', async () => {
  const options = {...};

  jest.mock('./authenticate', () => ({
    authenticate: jest.fn()
  }));

  const authenticate = require('./authenticate');

  authenticate.authenticate.mockReturnValue({
    data: mockOptions.access_token
  });

  const moduleUnderTest = await scheduler.schedule(options);

  expect(moduleUnderTest).toEqual({ data: 'success' });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **SHOULD NOT** use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) in function scope, it should be used in **MODULE** scope. Besides, for your case, I don't see any reason to use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) module.

E.g.

*authenticate.js*:

```js
const got = require('got');

const authenticate = async (options) => {
  let res = 'got';
  return { data: res.access_token };
};

exports.authenticate = authenticate;
```

*schedule.js*:

```js
const schedule = async (options) => {
  const authenticate = require('./authenticate');
  const login = await authenticate.authenticate(options);
  const result;
  result = {
    data: 'success'
  };

  return result;
};

exports.schedule = schedule;
```

*schedule.test.js:*

```js
const scheduler = require('./schedule');

jest.mock('./authenticate', () => ({
  authenticate: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('62074254', () => {
  test('[schedule]', async () => {
    const authenticate = require('./authenticate');
    const mockOptions = { access_token: '123' };

    authenticate.authenticate.mockReturnValue({
      data: mockOptions.access_token,
    });
    const options = {};
    const moduleUnderTest = await scheduler.schedule(options);

    expect(moduleUnderTest).toEqual({ data: 'success' });
    expect(authenticate.authenticate).toBeCalledWith({});
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62074254/schedule.test.js (10.742s)
  62074254
    ✓ [schedule] (6ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 schedule.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.202s
```

Comment: thanks for the function v. module scope heads up. as for rewire, that was an oversight and something vscode did using code complete. so that was a miss on my part. however, i've fixed both of those and authenticate.authenticate still isn't calling the mock function. its trying to authenticate. which is weird considering it is working in your example.